# JPA query left join without loading the joined entity field

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have 3 JPA entities such as:

```
@Entity
public class Link implements  {

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "network", referencedColumnName = "id")
   private Network network;
   //...
}

@Entity
public class Network implements LinkOwner {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "network")
    @Cascade(value = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private Set<Link>   links;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "project", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
     private Project Network.project;
  //...
 }


@Entity
public class Project {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", orphanRemoval = true)
    @Cascade(value = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private Set<Network>    networks;
 }
```

And I do a JPA query such as:

```
SELECT l FROM Link l left join fetch l.subnetwork sann   
where sann.project.id = :projectId
```

and it generates a SQL query similar to:

```
select * from RMT6.link, SUBNETWORK where link.subnetwork = SUBNETWORK.id 
and SUBNETWORK.project=?
```

How can I trigger a JPQL query that selects only the fields of the first entity and exclude those of the second one?
What do I need to change in my JPQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on your entity relationship, you don't need to use `JOIN` query, I think.

```
SELECT * FROM LINK l WHERE l.network.project.id = :projectId
```

Comment: @JayZee just FYI, if your are using the PKs of relations in hibernate/JPA, you don't need to create aliases or joins. This holds because if you see the underlying table already holds this PK information in form of foreign key. So no joins required for all the PKs from the FKs columns. Hope this helps you.

Comment: How do I use join on OneToMany with list? I tried 'fetch' that worked with explicit joining all the tables